# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@FiveStarBot.command(pass_context=True)
async def globalmessage(cxt, *, text : str):
    x = message.server.members
    for member in x:
        await FiveStarBot.send_message(member.name, text)
```

Why doesn't this work?

I'm beginner programmer

Comment: The error is clear. `message` is an object of type `Command`, and there is no such attribute as `server` in this class, i.e. you cannot do `message.server`.. Maybe you expected `message` to be of a different `type`?

Comment: can you fix my code and write it correctly pls?

Comment: @Roman how do you expect to learn things and not be a beginner anymore if you want others to do the job instead of you?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Try to write a clear title

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ctx` to resolve the message:

```
@FiveStarBot.command(pass_context=True)
async def globalmessage(ctx, *, text : str):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        await FiveStarBot.send_message(member, text)
```